# TYPO3 fluid dos't build form

Tags: typo3

```
<div style="display: none;">
    333
    <f:form name="user" object="{user}" action="show" extensionName="feusersplus" method="post" controller="User" id="change_background_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <f:form.hidden name="updateBackground" value="1"/>
        <f:form.upload property="backgroundimage" id="file_background_field"/>
    </f:form>
</div>
```

It don't build form. Why ? Where is a problem ?

Comment: 67 questions in 4 month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div style="display: none;">
```

Is a bit of a problem if you want the form to show up.